# dúvida sobre Maximum execution time

Tags: php

Bom, tenho um sisteminha que roda em php, e nele tenho várias funções. Como ele é um sistema em rede varias pessoas usam ele ao mesmo tempo. Porém comecei a receber o seguinte log de erro:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds
```

Pelo o que eu pude notar eu posso aumentar o limite no PHP.ini

Mas minha dúvida é o seguinte, e normal acontecer esse erro por tar vários usuários usando? aumentar o limite e uma gambiarra ou tem que ser feito a medida que tiver mais usuários?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adicione `set_time_limit(0);` no topo do script que está ocorrendo o problema

> A documentação diz que em `safe mode` isto não funciona, mas se o seu php estiver atualizado talvez nem exista mais o `safe mode`, já que ele é obsoleto desde o PHP 5.3 e foi removido no PHP 5.4, então `set_time_limit(0);` irá funcionar, a não ser que o administrador do servidor bloquei esta função

Não acho bom ajustar no `php.ini`, pois os 30 segundos são do meu ponto de vista úteis para evitar "gargalos".

**Pergunta:**

> Mas minha dúvida é o seguinte, e normal acontecer esse erro por tar vários usuários usando?

**Resposta:**

Não tem a ver diretamente, isto provavelmente é algo no teu script, se ele acessa um serviço externo e o serviço demora (como um webservice ou um banco de dados) isso pode ocorrer, mas geralmente o aumento é de poucos segundos, se o problema estiver ocorrendo é porque o script já gastou mais do que devia e a influência de muitos acessos só o afeta devido ao script estar "mal escrito" (não leve a mal)

**Documentação:** http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: bom algumas funções faz vários select no banco de dados. Pode ser isso?

Comment: @HugoBorges pode ser, pode ser um array muito grande que você gera fazendo o uso de memoria ser maior (isto geralmente afeta poucos segundos apenas), pode ser um loop gigante que você nem percebeu. Só olhando o script para poder afirmar.

Comment: era um problema no meu select, ele listava tudo hahaha. Coloquei um `LIMIT`